# Hilbert basis is this definition correct? Can't we get any simpler

Tags: hilbert-spaces, infinity, hermitian-matrices

There is a definition of Hilbert basis in this [paper](https://www.int.washington.edu/users/dbkaplan/324_01/DiracNotation.pdf)
(chapter 1.2) that says : $(e_{i})$ is a Hilbert basis iff
$$ (1). (e_{i}\dagger e_{j})=\delta_{i,j}$$
$$(2). \Sigma e_{i}e_{i}\dagger = I$$
where $I$ represents the identity matrix.

My question here is: isn't the (2). requierement enough for $(e_{i})$ to be an Hilbert basis? In other terms: does (2). imply (1). ?

In finite dimension I think it is the case. Because if we put the $(e_{i})$ vectors as columns in a matrix $H$ we have:
$$\Sigma e_{i}e_{i}\dagger = I \iff HH\dagger = I $$
which means $ H\dagger H= I $ which I think implies $  (e_{i}\dagger e_{j})=\delta_{i,j}$

I may be wrong... Thanks in advance

Comment: You're right, the cited paper deals with finite-dimensional spaces in 1.2.

Comment: But 1.2 talkes (implicitely) of finite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: I am not an expert (especially when it comes to infinite spaces) but I guess you are right: since 1.2 deals with the identity matrix, we are therefore in a finite-dimensional space. Unless infinite identity matrix exists...